# Small help var with a country code value (number) = open jpg

Tags: php

I have a portal build in PHP + mysql. There's a specific field with the country code value ie "351" in number format.

Can I use the var countrycode.jpg to open the respective file?

something like

```
$var = "351"
<img src=$var.jpg>
```

ps: i have a folder with all country codes in (number).jpg format

sorry my dumb question. Thanks in advance for any help.
Cheers

Comment: `<img src="<?php echo $var; ?>.jpg">`

Comment: Instead of asking questions like "Can I ...", just test it. If you run into some specific issue while testing it, then show us your attempt (instead of some "something like this" pseudo code) and explain the specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use php inside html element use echo, something like

```
<img src="<?php echo $var ?>.jpg">
```

Comment: thank you very much Sir. I know it could look easy but I was lost with this. I wasn't using echo (probably why it wasn't working). Thanks again!!

Comment: got it. Thanks.

I did a small change.
,,,
echo "<td><img src='$call_ccode.jpg' width='23' height='13'>

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, but this is what I assume you want to achieve.

you want to show the image `351.jpg` and that actually exists on your server then you can show it like this.

```
$var = 351;
<img src="<?php echo $var; ?>.jpg ">
```